# SignalR is not Async?

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

While messing around with SignalR I found a behaviour that confuse me.

Calling StartCountDown from a client then make a call  to Join behaves like

- wait 10 seconds
- Call clients CountDownStarted
- Then call PlayerJoined

What I expected.

- Call start CountDown, return
- immediately call PlayerJoined
- After 10 seconds complete CountDownStarted.

```
    public class AHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task Join(string player)
        {
            await Clients.All.PlayerJoined(player);
        }
        public async Task StartCountDown()
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            await Clients.All.CountDownStarted();
        }
    }
```

This is from a SignalR Hub

Comment: Would you believe me if I told you, `await` actually means "*await*"

Comment: Yes, but I wan't to handle other request concurrently that is why I await so the thread can handle other requests.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do `await Task.WhenAll(StartCountDown(), Join(player))`

Comment: Or `WhenAny` ... However, at about this stage you should probably research more about the async and await pattern and tasks

Comment: @juharr

Basically, I want a timer that delays for a while until the game starts, while players are joining.

This is a SignalR Hub

Comment: System.Threading.Timer ?

Comment: @TheGeneral Yes System.Timer.Timer or System.Thread.Timer are viable solutions.

It's just my mental model how .net core webcontext handles async await requests.

Comment: If you want to run a task (fire and forget) you could just call `_ = StartCountDownAsync();` There are downsides to this, meaning it runs unobserved, and without a cancellation token it cant be stopped.

Comment: Yeah, we can take another example which makes a little more sense in this context.

Let's say I have an endpoint DownloadFromSlowApi(...)
I want to await this and send to clients.

While this is downloading I would like for clients to call other methods on my hub concurrently.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common misconception about the *async and await pattern*. Awaiting something does actually await the completion of the task.

If you want to run the task unobserved (or colloquially known as fire and forget), you could do thus

```
// task gets started hot and unobserved, remove the warning with a discard
_ = StartCountDownAsync();
```

***Note** : An exception that's raised in a method that returns a `Task` or `Task<TResult>` is stored in the returned task. If you don't await the task or explicitly check for exceptions, the *exception* is lost. If you `await` the task, its *exception* is rethrown.*

As a best practice, you should always `await` the call.

Though, you have other options. Which is to start a task, complete other tasks, and then await the completion of the original

**Given**

```
public async Task SomeTask1() {  }
public async Task SomeTask2() {  }
public async Task SlowApiAsync() {  }
```

You might want

```
var slowApiTask = SlowApiAsync();

await SomeTask1();
await SomeTask2();

await slowApiTask;
```

Or if you want to run all the tasks concurrently (and yet await them all)

```
var slowApiTask = SlowApiAsync();

var task1 = SomeTask1();
var task2 = SomeTask2();

await Task.WhenAll(slowApiTask,task1,task2)
```

Comment: I will pick as accepted if you could provide answer that is in the context which I asked. That is within a signalR hub

Comment: @JonatanAlmén paste a minimal example of your hub code into the question. I mean, I have no idea at this stage how to change my answer, its indifferent of hub code until I see a concrete example of what you have

Comment: added a working example of a signalr hub, how would you add a delay while still being able having players to join.

Comment: "*That is within a signalR hub*" i am not sure what you want to write... or what your problem is in regards to having this in the context of a hub

Comment: I want to add a request that delays the game start for some time, while this is counting down I want players to be able to join.